# Writing query with new 'where'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to do a simple query with Rails 3 where clause.

I have the following:

```
  Participant.find(:first, :conditions => ["participants.role = ? AND participants.board_id = ?", "Manager", board.id])
```

Which works very well. I am trying to rewrite it the Rails 3 way as follows:

```
Participant.where(:board => board, :role => "Manager")
```

However this does not work. Is there a way to stipulate first with the where to get the same return as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Participant.where(:board_id => board.id, :role => "Manager").first
```